# Yellow Interface as Source Table in ODI using SDK

Tags: oracle, sdk, oracle-data-integrator

How to assign a temporary target datastore of a pre-existing yellow interface as the source table while creating an interface using ODI SDK?

For a simple source table, the code would go as:
    OdiDataStore SourceDS = ((IOdiDataStoreFinder)odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().getFinder(OdiDataStore.class)).findByName(table_Name, model_Name);

I've tried getting the interface as an OdiInterface object and using    getTargetDataStore() or getUnderlyingTable() on it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using the OdiInterface object or the Target Datastore both work whith an instance of [InterfaceActionAddSourceDatastore](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e17060/toc.htm).
The 3rd of the 4th constructors are the ones of interest for a temporary datastore as a source.

`InterfaceActionAddSourceDataStore(OdiInterface.TargetDataStore pDataStore, DataSet pDataSet, IAliasComputer pAliasComputer, IClauseImporter pClauseImporter, IAutoMappingComputer pAutoMappingComputer)`

`InterfaceActionAddSourceDataStore(OdiInterface pInterface, DataSet pDataSet, IAliasComputer pAliasComputer, IClauseImporter pClauseImporter, IAutoMappingComputer pAutoMappingComputer)`

The performAction method actually does the change.